# List in JQuery/HTML, cannot delete some items

Tags: jquery

This list program enables you to dynamically add and delete items.

Add works fine.
Delete only deletes items that were already there (Apple, banana and orange) but not items that I have added. Please help!

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#newItemForm').on('submit', function(e){
                addElements(e);
            });

            // Delete elements from the list
            $('.delete').click(function(){
                $(this).parent.remove();
            });

        });

        // Add new elements to the list
        function addElements(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            var newText = $('input:text').val();
            $('input:text').val('');
            $('#myList').append("<li>"+newText+"<button class='delete'>Delete</button></li>");
        }

    </script>

    <h1>My List</h1>
    <body>
    <ol id="myList">
        <li>Apple<button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
        <li>Banana<button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
        <li>Orange<button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
    </ol>

    <form id=newItemForm>
        <input type="text" id="newItem" value="New Item"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Add to list"/>
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the `click` callback to the dynamic elements added:

```
function addElements(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            var newText = $('input:text').val();
            $('input:text').val('');
            var $el = $("<li>"+newText+"<button class='delete'>Delete</button></li>");

            $('#myList').append($el);
            $(".delete", $el).click(function(){ $(this).parent.remove(); });
        }
```

**EDIT:**

A better way would be to use :

```
$('#myList').on('click', '.delete', function() {
    $(this).parent.remove();
});
```

This will work for dynamic elements without having to rebind the click callback

Comment: This is weird but I made the changes to the code and it's still not working. I feel like something is missing.

Comment: @jimbo123 Which way did you try from my answer?

Comment: the addElements function, I took everything out and placed into the document.ready() part. Then I added the $('li').on('click')...... part of the code beneath it

Comment: @jimbo123 mmh, weird, it should've work. Did you try the first way?

Comment: sorry for late reply but i wasnt sure. I tried the second way and it didn't work but when I changed $('li') to $('#myList') it worked!

Comment: @jimbo123 Yep, that's called event delegation, I've edited my answer for helping others as well